# Display stream of Images like a video in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, video-streaming

I have created a PHP file extract images from MySQL database and display them as a sequence of images updated every half second. So every half second the page gets updated and a new picture comes up using setInterval method in JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function() {
    var myImageElement = document.getElementById('myImage');
    myImageElement.src ='http://145.71.111.87/getImage.php?id='+ counter;
}, 500);});
```

counter is an id changed every time and the image that match this id get fetched every time. I want to display this stream in a similar way to a video in YouTube for instance, so I could stop, play and move the playing slider. Obviously by having the counter we can get any image in any position of the sequence.

Comment: Where is `counter` defined ?

Comment: I did not put the definition because that is what I want to change, in my case at the moment it is just increasing gradually @guest271314

Comment: Does "slide show" describe what you want to do? I doubt that an image every half-second is going to look like a video. And something else to consider: load the images (one by one) beforehand (in another hidden div, maybe?) and then _display_ them every half-second. While an image is displayed, load the next image. That way, you can have a better experience for users with slow connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `button` elements , `switch` ,`.index()`

html

```
<img id="myImage" src="" />
<button>&leftarrow;</button><button>stop</button><button>start</button><button>&rightarrow;</button><label></label>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0, interval, label = $("label")
  , fx = function() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {     
      var myImageElement = document.getElementById("myImage");
      myImageElement.onload = function() {label.html(counter)};
      myImageElement.src = "/path/to/image/getImage.php?id=" + counter;     
      ++counter;
    }, 500);
    };
  fx()
  $("button").click(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    switch ($(this).index("button")) {
      case 0: label.html(--counter);break;
      case 1: clearInterval(interval);break;
      case 2: fx();break;
      case 3: label.html(++counter);break;
    };
  })
});
```